# Is it possible to prioritize (give a priority) to specific Akka's Actor?

Tags: akka, actor

I've made my research about Akka Framework,
And I would like to know ;
Is it possible to give a priority to a specific actor?
I mean - actors are working while getting a "let" message from the queue,
Is there an option to let an actor work even when it's not his turn yet to work?

Comment: Normally I assign high priority actors to fix pool dispatcher with pre-allocated pool size, and other actors to the normal dispatcher in the akka config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, yes.

One of the parts of your Actor configuration is which [Dispatcher](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html#more-dispatcher-configuration-examples) those actors will use. A dispatcher is what connects the actor to the actual threads that will execute the work. (Dispatchers default to ForkJoinPools, but can also be dedicated thread pools or even threads dedicated to a specific actor.)

So the typical way you give an Actor "priority" is to give it a dedicated dispatcher, and thereby dedicated threads. For example, Akka itself does this for its internal messages: they run on a dedicated dispatcher so that even you deploy a bunch of poorly written actors that block the threads, Akka itself can still function.

I put "priority" in quotes, because you aren't guaranteeing a specific order of processing. (There are other ways to do that, but not across Actors.) But you are solving the case where you want specific actors to always have a greater access to resources and/or specific actors to get executed promptly.

(In theory, you could take this even further and create a ThreadPoolExecutor with higher priority threads, and then create a Dispatcher based on that ThreadPoolExecutor. That would truly give OS-level priority to an Actor, but that would only be likely relevant in very unusual circumstances.)

EDIT TO RESPOND TO "do mailboxes and dispatchers are the same" [sic]?

No. Each actor has a mailbox. So sometimes we talk about the behavior of mailboxes when discussing the behavior of actors, as the behavior of the mailbox governs the ordering of the actor's message processing.

But dispatchers are a distinct concept. Actors have a dispatcher, but it is many to one. (i.e. each Actor has one mailbox, but there may be many actors associated with a single dispatcher.)

For example, a real world situation might be:

1. System actors are processed by the internal dispatcher. To quote the docs "To protect the internal Actors that are spawned by the various Akka modules, a separate internal dispatcher is used by default." i.e. no matter how badly screwed up your own code might be, you can't screw up the heartbeat processing and other system messages because they are running on their own dispatcher, and thus their own threads.
2. Most actors (millions of them perhaps) are processed by the default dispatcher. Huge numbers of actors, as long as they are well behaved, can be handled with a tiny number of threads. So they might all be configured to use the default dispatcher.
3. Badly behaved actors (such as those that block) might be configured to be processed by a dedicated "blocking" dispatcher. By isolating blocking dispatchers into a separate dispatcher they don't impact the response time of the default dispatcher.
4. Although I don't see this often, you might also have a dispatcher for extremely response time sensitive actors that gives them a dedicated thread pool. Or even a "pinned" dispatcher that gives an actor a dedicated thread.

As I mentioned this isn't really "priority", this is "dedicated resources". Because one of the critical aspects of actors is that the are location independent. So if Actor A is on Node A, and Actor B is on Node B, I can't guarantee that Actor A will ALWAYS act first. Because doing so would involve an ASTRONOMINCAL amount of overhead between nodes. All I can reasonably do is give Actor A dedicated resources so that I know that Actor A should always be able to act quickly.

Note that this is what the internal dispatcher does as well. We don't *guarantee* that heartbeat messages are always processed first, but we do make sure that there are always threads available to process system messages, even if some bad user code has blocked the default dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
However, do mailboxes and dispatchers are the same?

Comment: Editing answer to address.